# unindent does not match any outer indentation level don't understand my mistake

Tags: python

I'm new to python and don't understand my mistake
Can you help me please ?

error : unindent does not match any outer indentation level :16

````
pygame.init()


# fenetre de jeux
pygame.display.set_caption("DoDo Game")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 720))

background = pygame.image.load('assets/bg.jpg')
running = True
# tant que la condition est vrai
while running:

    #appliquer l'arriere plan

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))




   for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()```
````

Comment: ``for event in pygame.event.get():`` isn't properly indented

Comment: The `for` loop is indented one space less than the `screen.blit()` line.

Answer (score 0):

Purely some spacing/tabs out of line

```
pygame.init()


# fenetre de jeux
pygame.display.set_caption("DoDo Game")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 720))

background = pygame.image.load("assets/bg.jpg")
running = True
# tant que la condition est vrai
while running:

    # appliquer l'arriere plan

    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
```